# difference between library , package , module in js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, redux

I have started to learn react and I am very confused with the concept of packages.
 and why we can't just use a simple link as cdn and there is a module which i don't understand it and what's npm and why i have to use it with react

Comment: In simple terms, npm downloads and organizes JavaScript libraries for you. Technically, there are a lot of other ways to integrate other people's code with your own, but it comes with a bunch of hard problems you're not aware of yet.

Answer (score 5):

Not trying to give the definite answer here, but trying to explain the 3 terms as simple as I can:

A module is just a file containing lines of JavaScript code.

A library uses one or many modules to provide a set of features.

A package is a downloadable, versioned library. Think of someone putting it in a box and shipping it to you, so you can import it and use it in combination with your own code.

Answer (score 1):

so I came with conclusion and hope you tell me if I get it right or not .

-Module : it is justba javascript file but it's different from normal script that it has its own scope so you have to use import or export to exchange information between modules.

-Library : it is a group of modules or scripts that it is responsible for the function you want .

-package : can be one or more libraries but it is also contain files that don't deal with the functionality but it's only role to make sure the libraries and functional file work properly .

like react package it is come with react library deals with the functionality and also has babel compiler to make browser read and understand react library.

Answer (score 0):

It is very much possible to use a simple link such as a [CDN](https://reactjs.org/docs/cdn-links.html). Many packages also have links available, such as material UI. However, it quickly becomes unmanageable to use CDN links when your project grows, and it can affect performance and load times of your site.

Npm stands for Node package manager. It handles packaging for Node, where it would not be suitable to use a simple link.

It turns out that it is possible to also use npm  for web applications, by combining it with a bundler. The bundler (such as webpack) takes all of your modules (JavaScript files and npm packages) and bundles it together so that you get a single script which you can run in the browser.

Answer (score -1):

Library:
A library is a collection of code resources (modules) that provide various functionalities and tools for software development. Libraries are designed to be reusable and save developers time by offering pre-built solutions for common tasks. They can include modules for a wide range of purposes, such as math calculations, file handling, networking, and more.

Module:
A module is a single file containing Python code that defines functions, classes, and variables. It is a self-contained unit that can be imported and used in other Python programs. Modules promote code organization, reusability, and separation of concerns. For example, the `math` module in Python provides mathematical functions like `sqrt()` and `sin()`, making them accessible through the module's namespace.

Package:
A package is a way to organize related modules into a directory hierarchy. It typically includes an `__init__.py` file that signifies the directory as a package and allows it to be imported as a whole. Packages help structure larger code projects, preventing naming conflicts and providing a clear organization of code modules. An example is the `numpy` package, which includes various modules for numerical computations.